# How can I fix the caption position in figures?

Tags: captions, positioning, kile

Running the following code in Kile, I obtain a caption position of the first image that is different from the second one since the text inserted in the second picture is less than the first one. This is unaesthetic.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics[scale=0.80]{examplesignalchangesfrequency.png}
\caption{Example of time domain oscillating signal which contains four frequencies at four different times.}
\label{exampletimedomainsignal}
\end{figure}

Fig. \ref{exampleFFTtimedomainsignal} is the corresponding frequency spectrum.
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\includegraphics[scale=0.80]{exampleFFTsignalchangesfrequency.png}
\caption{Example of FFT applied to the signal in figure \ref{exampletimedomainsignal}.}
\label{exampleFFTtimedomainsignal}
\end{figure}
```

This is what I mean:

[image]

How can I fix this problem in a way that, for example, captions are all in the same position that is, in this case, the position of the first image ? So they are all starting on the "extreme left position" whatever is the length of text to be inserted in ?

Comment: @Marijn it could, however the Simon Dispa answer is more straightforward in my case.

Comment: I understand the answer by Simon is more directly applicable to your specific situation, however for the organization of the site as a whole I think it's a good idea to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By loading the package `caption` it is possible to configure the format of all document captions. For example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption} % added <<<<<<<    
\captionsetup[figure]{hangindent=0pt, singlelinecheck=false}% added <<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.80]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example of time domain oscillating signal which contains four frequencies at four different times.}
    \label{exampletimedomainsignal}
\end{figure}

Fig. \ref{exampleFFTtimedomainsignal} is the corresponding frequency spectrum.
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.80]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Example of FFT applied to the signal in figure~\ref{exampletimedomainsignal}.}
    \label{exampleFFTtimedomainsignal}
\end{figure}    
    
\end{document}
```

The standard LATEX document classes (article, report, and book) automatically center a caption if it fits in one single line.

`singlelinecheck=false` switches this extra centering off.

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

This uses a minipage to match both the left and right edges of the caption to the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\sbox0{\includegraphics[scale=0.80]{example-image}}% measure width
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
\usebox0
\caption{Example of time domain oscillating signal which contains four frequencies at four different times.}
\label{exampletimedomainsignal}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```